# Sending data on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm using Ajax (along with Django) to perform some action on button click. Before I even get to the view, I am unable to pass data to the javascript function. What is going wrong? How can I pass the button's ID data to the function? I get the message that my `request_data` is Undefined.

template.html

```
<button class="btn-green" onclick="request_access()" id="{{ data }}">Join Group</button>
```

javascript.js

```
function request_access(){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var request_data = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("data: " + request_data);
    $.post({
        url: "request_access/",
        data : { request_data: request_data},
        success : function(json) {
            $("#request-access").hide();
            console.log("requested access complete");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: pass the data into the function
request_data( {{ data }} )

Comment: Can you show us the generated html AND the django view function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax of **[`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)** is not correct, also pass the `this` instance in `onclick` handler. Inside the function `this` refers to window object not the clicked DOM element.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn-green" onclick="request_access(this)" id="{{ data }}">Join Group</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
function request_access($this){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var request_data = $this.id;
    console.log("data: " + request_data)
    $.post( "request_access",{ request_data: request_data},function(json) {
         $("#request-access").hide();
         console.log("requested access complete");
    })
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked @Pranav C Balan Thank you so much

Comment: @steph : glad to help :)

Comment: One more question @PranavCBalan ! I'm now having issues actually calling the django view- any idea what's going on? I added my urls.py to the question...

Comment: @steph : sorry I don't know much about django :). It's better to add an another question with your new problem

Answer (score 1):

Bind the onclick event using jquery also, like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.btn-green').on('click', function(e) {
          var request_data = $(this).attr('id');
          $.post .......
          .....
    })
})
```

and get rid of the `onclick="request_access()"` in html

ALSO: Maybe you haven't pass "data" to the django template. Can you show us the generated html AND the django view function?

Comment: Generated html: `<button class="btn-green" onclick="request_access({'profile': <Profile: fwilliams>, 'category': <Category: Academy>})" id="{'profile': <Profile: fwilliams>, 'category': <Category: Academy>}">Join Group</button>`
I haven't written the view function yet- trying to pass data to the js function first! The `console.log("data: " + request_data);` shows the request_data as undefined ?

Answer (score 1):

this is the window object.
don't use eventhandlers within html-tags. this is one reason. split your javascript code and your html structure.

if you cannot do that: use the window.event to detect the event-owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn-green" onclick="request_access('{{ data }}')" id="{{ data }}">Join Group</button>
```

javascript.js

```
function request_access(id){

    var request_data =id;
    console.log("data: " + request_data);
    $.post({
        url: "request_access",
        data : { request_data: request_data},
        success : function(json) {
            $("#request-access").hide();
            console.log("requested access complete");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: when I try your solution, i get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` @user1048123